# Android SDK authentication with product flavours

Tags: here-api

I am creating multiple versions of an app using product flavors.  Each app version has a different application id suffix.

Is there any way to generate Here Android SDK Premium app id and key using the android app package name without the suffixes from the product flavors or are separate credentials required for each flavor?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by product flavours. In general, any change in package name requires a new license key. One package can have only one license key.

Comment: I am using [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) to generate build variants so that if the package name is MappingDemo I can create build variants like  MappingDemo.FullRelease and MappingDemo.DemoRelease for example.  Then the Here API credentials have to be generated for each build variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate credentials for each of the product flavours. You have to provide your build variant values using the SDK method (instead of hardcoding in manifest file). Please refer the documentation in https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/ApplicationContext.html#ApplicationContext-android.content.Context-